# Issues upgrading from rspec 2.7 to rspec 2.12

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to upgrade an old (dormant for 1 year) project from Rails 3.1 and Rspec 2.7 to Rails 3.2 and Rspec 2.12.

The initial upgrade to Rails 3.2 went fine and the application works, but running the tests under Rspec produced lots of warnings about:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern 
will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods
directly in RSpec::Rails::TestUnitAssertionAdapter instead.
```

A web search suggested upgrading to Rspec 2.8 as this was apparently a problem in 2.7 which has been fixed.  I let "bundle update" take me all the way to the latest version (2.12.0) but now tests which were working in 2.7 won't run at all under 2.12

The problem comes in the Controller tests, when they try to fake the login (almost all the controller actions require you to be logged in before you can do anything).

Previously this was achieved by this method in `spec_helper.rb`

```
def test_login(user)
   controller.sign_in(user)
end
```

which invoked a method in `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb` to do the actual login.

Now however it gets an error about `controller` being an undefined variable.  Something structural seems to have changed, but I'm struggling to discover what, or how to achieve login from a controller test.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies - I eventually managed to find the explanation for this myself.

The problem lay in the Gemfile which contained:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.8.0'
end
```

That worked fine with earlier versions of rspec, but not now.  By changing it to read:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.8.0'
end
```

and then doing a `bundle update` the problem documented above magically went away.